# Is a 2d array set up in memory contiguously similar to a 1d array simulating a 2d one?

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

Consider the 2 type of array declarations:

```
T x [rows * cols];  // type 1
T y [rows][cols];   // type 2
```

I usually use the first type ( type 1) where then I know to index using x[row * cols + col]

however if I want to copy a 2d array into a 1d array simulating a 2d array  ie: copy type2 -> type1. If these are guaranteed to be laid out the same way in memory can I just do a memcpy of one to the other?  Currently I have a loop as such but if the memory is the same layout in both I am thinking I can just do a memcpy. Consider the following public constructor below.

```
public:
  // construct a matrix from a 2d array
  template <unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
  Matrix ( T (&twoDArray)[N][M]  )  : rows_(N), cols_(M), matrixData_(new T[rows_*cols_]) 
  {
    // is there a refactor here? Maybe to memcpy?
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_ ; ++i )
    {
      for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols_ ; ++j )
      {
        matrixData_[ i * cols_ + j ] = twoDArray[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  private:
  unsigned int rows_;
  unsigned int cols_;
  T* matrixData_;
```

Comment: "type 2" is not even legal C++.

Comment: You want:

`T **y = new T*[row];   // type 2`

Comment: @Smac89: Nobody wants that.

Comment: sorry the new declaration was wrong.. that's another reason why use type 1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2d array (the kind you declared) is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.  That doesn't mean you should use memcpy on it.  Especially not in a template like you are doing, because memcpy may not work correctly for `T`.  You can keep what you have.  Here is how I might write it though (if you can't use C++11, then just use a regular counting for loop):

```
template <unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
Matrix ( T (&twoDArray)[N][M]  )  : rows_(N), cols_(M), matrixData_(new T[rows_*cols_]) 
{
    T * out = matrixData_;
    for (auto const & sub : twoDArray)
        out = std::copy(std::begin(sub), std::end(sub), out);
}
```

Or better yet, just use `std::vector`.  Then you don't have to implement a copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor. (you have implemented all three of those, right?)

Comment: yes, I have all 5 since I am using c++11. I was trying to keep contiguous memory for speed and was trying to see if I could do this without using a vector<vector<T> > but it seems c++ doesn't allow you to overload the operator[] with more than one argument so you can't do something like m[1,1] = 5  
`  // immutable 
  const T* operator[] (unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const
  {
    return matrixData_[row * cols_ + col]; 
  }

  // mutable
  T* operator[] (unsigned int row, unsigned int col) 
  {
    return matrixData_[row * cols_ + col]; 
  }
`

Comment: any thoughts on that?  pretty cool collection loop you put there, I like it.

Comment: @bjackfly: I didn't mean to use `vector` instead of your matrix class.  I meant to use `vector` *inside* your class, instead of manually managing memory.

Comment: I know what you meant, I was saying I was trying to have a single array inside the matrix instead of a vector< vector<T> > inside the matrix. The nice thing about the vector is then  you have the operator[] return a vector. As in Vector<Object>& operator[] ( const unsigned int& ).  The nice thing here is then the client can say m[1][2] = 5;

Comment: I didn't mean that either.  I meant just `vector<T>`.  Just like you are doing now, using a 1d array to act as a 2d array, but managed automatically.

Comment: LOL! ok, got it. I was thinking about my operator issue. Yes you are right I could just use a vector in this case and have the same indexing rules. good call.

Comment: @bjackfly: As far as my thoughts on the `operator[]` issue, I agree with this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html -- read the next two pages (13.11 and 13.12) also.

Comment: Wow! excellent. ok they are showing the move this to a chat link for extended comments so I better cut it off here but this is a perfect example! Thanks. Is there a way I can add you as a friend on here or something? This has been most helpful.

Comment: @bjackfly: Stackoverflow has no such features.  Questions, and answers, that's it.  Don't worry, there are plenty of other highly competent C++ programmers on here who will answer your future questions.

Answer (score 3):

It depends, but usually the compiler will make a simple T x[rows][columns] behave like a T x[rows * columns. Unless you dynamic declare the memory like

```
T** x = new T*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    x[i] = new T[columns];
```

In this example they are different.